# Formatting raggedright in booktabs. Why am I getting a \noalign error?

Tags: tables, errors, booktabs

I have a `\sidewaystable` that is also a `\threeparttable`. I'm trying to produce it using booktabs. In the shape columns there are words with more than 8 letters that TeX keeps hyphenating. The column widths have been set to their current values to ensure that the entire table fits on an A4 page.

Whether or not I include the `\noalign{smallskip}` after the `\toprule` and `\midrule` I get the error:

```
! Misplaced \cr.
\reserved@c ->\ifnum 0=`{}\fi \cr 

l.34 \toprule
             \noalign{smallskip}
?
```

Here is an example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openleft,draft]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=4.0cm, rmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{mathpazo}    
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[htp]
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{center}
\caption{Key morphological characteristics}
\label{tab:cycadnmorph}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}
{>{\raggedright}p{3.05cm}>{\raggedright}p{0.6cm}>{\raggedright}p{1.5cm}>{\raggedright}p{2cm}>{\raggedright}p{1.75cm}>{\raggedright}p{1.75cm}>{\raggedright}p{0.25cm}>{\raggedright}p{2cm}>{\raggedright}p{1.5cm}>{\raggedright}p{1.75cm}>{\raggedright}p{1.75cm}}}
\tabularnewline
\toprule\noalign{smallskip}
&&C&&&&&H&&&\tabularnewline
\cmidrule{3-6}
\cmidrule{8-11}
Species&OTU\tnote{a}&Cells\tnote{b}&Shape&Length\tnote{c}&Width\tnote{c}&&Shape&(\%)\tnote{d}&Length\tnote{c}&Width\tnote{c}\tabularnewline
\midrule\noalign{smallskip}
\emph{species name}&A&number (min, max)&Shape&number (min, max)&number (min, max)&&Shape Bigshape biggershape&number (min, max)&number (min, max)&number (min, max)\tabularnewline
\emph{species name}&A&number (min, max)&Shape&number (min, max)&number (min, max)&&Shape Bigshape biggershape&number (min, max)&number (min, max)&number (min, max)\tabularnewline
\emph{species name}&A&number (min, max)&Shape&number (min, max)&number (min, max)&&Shape Bigshape biggershape&number (min, max)&number (min, max)&number (min, max)\tabularnewline
\emph{species name}&A&number (min, max)&Shape&number (min, max)&number (min, max)&&Shape Bigshape biggershape&number (min, max)&number (min, max)&number (min, max)\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [a] Data adapted.
\item [b] ND, no data.
\item [c] Accession numbers
\item[d] D
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{sidewaystable}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command to use is `\addlinespace`; you have also a wrong `}`:

```
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{
  >{\raggedright}p{3.05cm}
  >{\raggedright}p{0.6cm}
  >{\raggedright}p{1.5cm}
  >{\raggedright}p{2cm}
  >{\raggedright}p{1.75cm}
  >{\raggedright}p{1.75cm}
  >{\raggedright}p{0.25cm}
  >{\raggedright}p{2cm}
  >{\raggedright}p{1.5cm}
  >{\raggedright}p{1.75cm}
  >{\raggedright}p{1.75cm}
}
\toprule\addlinespace[\smallskipamount]
```

However, I don't think that adding such a space is needed.

There are other points where your code can be improved. For example, defining

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
```

in the preamble, your tabular preamble can be reduced to

```
\begin{tabular}{
  P{3.05cm}
  P{0.6cm}
  P{1.5cm}
  P{2cm}
  P{1.75cm}
  P{1.75cm}
  P{0.25cm}
  P{2cm}
  P{1.5cm}
  P{1.75cm}
  >{\arraybackslash}P{1.75cm}
}
```

so that you're not required to use `\tabularnewline` for ending table rows.

The table enclosure can be more simply

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[htp]
\caption{Key morphological characteristics}
\label{tab:cycadnmorph}
\centering\scriptsize
\begin{threeparttable}
...<the tabular>...
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [a] Data adapted.
\item [b] ND, no data.
\item [c] Accession numbers
\item[d] D
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaysttable}
```

Comment: Replacing `\noalign{smallskip}` with `\addlinespace` does not remove the error message regarding `\toprule`. Any further suggestions?

Comment: @Will See the edited answer: you also had a wrong `}` (and the first `\tabularnewline` was out of place).

Comment: Apologies for not properly checking your answer. It worked brilliantly.